# TinyMCE Setting Content Issue

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

I'm trying to set the content of the TinyMCE editor but I'm not having much luck. I've tried both setting the HTML beforehand and initializing the editor, and setting the content after the editor is initialized but to no avail - I'm able to reproduce that one in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k4Lnjycs/2/) (I can't reproduce setting the content first because it uses variable HTML from the database to set it).

Pretty much what I'm trying to do is this with my own code:

```
            Editor.innerHTML += '<label>Description</label><br><div id="AC-Description">' + data.Data.Description + '</div><br><br>'; // Editor is just a div & data is a json object return from an ajax call
            tinymce.init({
                selector: '#AC-Description'
            });
            tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(data.Data.Description); // does not work, same as in example fiddle.
            tinymce.get('AC-Description').setContent(data.Data.Description); // does not work either, same as in example fiddle
```

Before the editor is initialized, the data.Data.Description does show text in the DIV and then TinyMCE ignores it when it initializes.

I'm just at a lost, especially since it isn't working on JSFiddle too. Anyone else have issues with this before and/or am I just missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Try to set the content when the editor has been initialized by listening to the *init* event like:

```
tinymce.init({
                selector: '#Editor'
            });

tinymce.get('Editor').on('init', function(e){
                e.target.setContent('test'); 
            });
```

Comment: This did work for static content, in terms of the fiddle so that's a plus. Unfortunately it still wouldn't set the content of tinymce to what the data in the JSON object is --- oddly enough now I'm just setting the HTML and then initialize the editor (like I've been trying) and it's working now... No idea. Thanks for the idea though!!

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing running code I can't say for sure but the issue here is almost certainly a timing issue of when your JavaScript run.

The TinyMCE `init()` function is **asynchronous**.  When you call `init()` it takes some time for the process to complete.  In your code example you are immediately trying to call either `activeEditor` or `get()` but there is likely no initialized editor so both of these attempts are failing.

The correct way to make sure that TinyMCE is fully initialized is to rely on the `init` event. This event is fired after TinyMCE is fully initialized and ready for interaction.

To load content via the `init()` you can do something like this:

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea",
  plugins: ["advlist autolink lists ..."],
  toolbar: "undo redo | bullist numlist ...",
  setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('init', function (e) {
      //this gets executed AFTER TinyMCE is fully initialized
      editor.setContent('<p>This is content set via the init function</p>');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, solved with `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```js
 import tinymce from 'tinymce';
 
 tinymce.init({
      selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
      toolbar: ' bold italic underline bullist',
      menubar: '',
      width : "926",
      placeholder: $('.annotation-session').data('placeholder'),
      plugins: 'lists',
      lists_indent_on_tab: false,
      setup: function (editor) {
          editor.on('init', function (e) {
              editor.setContent(window.userNotes.note);
          });
      }
  });
  
  //If you want you can set on startup line 12 - 14
  //And also on another funcion doing this:
  //Empty 
  tinymce.activeEditor.setContent('');  
  if (yourVariable !== '') {
      tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(yourVariable)
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="annotation-session">
```